# SQL server: Find Max, 2nd Max and 3rd Max values >> Query processing time question

Tags: performance, max

I'm learning SQL and I'm trying to find an explanation for the behavior of the code below.
Currently, with this code, I can obtain the Max, 2nd Max, and 3rd Max values out of a column table (table name: #TEMP_EST_FYQ). This table has 3 attributes and more than 65K tuples.
The code provides the expected results and the query executes in less than a second for 2nd Max and 3rd Max values BUT for the Max, the query takes over 8 minutes to complete.
I'm curious about what could be the reason for this. Thanks in advance!

```
--Query executes in: +8 mins 
SELECT DISTINCT SE_Request_FYQ
                FROM #TEMP_EST_FYQ A
                WHERE (0) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(SE_Request_FYQ)) 
                                    FROM #TEMP_EST_FYQ B
                                    WHERE B.SE_Request_FYQ > A.SE_Request_FYQ )
--Query executes in: -1 sec
SELECT DISTINCT SE_Request_FYQ
                FROM #TEMP_EST_FYQ A
                WHERE (1) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(SE_Request_FYQ)) 
                                    FROM #TEMP_EST_FYQ B
                                    WHERE B.SE_Request_FYQ > A.SE_Request_FYQ )
--Query executes in: -1 sec
SELECT DISTINCT SE_Request_FYQ
                FROM #TEMP_EST_FYQ A
                WHERE (2) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(SE_Request_FYQ)) 
                                    FROM #TEMP_EST_FYQ B
                                    WHERE B.SE_Request_FYQ > A.SE_Request_FYQ )
```

Value results:

- "2022-Q1"   Max
- "2021-Q4"   2nd Max
- "2021-Q3"   3rd Max

Answer (score 0):

I don't/can't know the exact reason for performance without checking the execution plans.  For the max value, I suggest just doing a max query:

```sql
SELECT MAX(SE_Request_FYQ)
FROM #TEMP_EST_FYQ;
```

For this query, an index on `SE_Request_FYQ` should let SQL Server find the max value almost immediately.  For the second and third highest, use `DENSE_RANK`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SE_Request_FYQ DESC) rnk
    FROM #TEMP_EST_FYQ
)

SELECT SE_Request_FYQ
FROM cte
WHERE rnk IN (2, 3);
```

This query should also benefit from the same index suggested above for the max query.